# Apache Tomcat in Eclipse with a proxied network

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, proxy, struts, localhost

I am on a network that accesses internet via a proxy.
I have a java/struts application that I am running via eclipse(and Tomcat apache).

When I hit a url like http://localhost:8080/fooUrl, this is shown on the browser :
"`Self-referential requests to proxy are forbidden`"

I cannot disable the proxy as I need to access internet via my application.

Any suggestions, why I am being prohibited to make a localhost request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Preferences>Network connections settings, did you specify the proxy bypass for localhost / 127.0.0.1 ?
These 2 rules are there by default.

Comment: thanks buddy. yes, that was it. the rules where different in my network config.